# "No ESLint configuration found" when I use gulp-eslint

Tags: eslint

This is my gulpfile

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/nodeuii/**/*.js')
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

But:

> No ESLint configuration found

Comment: Do you have `.eslintrc` file in your project?

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/nodeuii/**/*.js')
        .pipe(eslint({
            configFile: 'eslintrc.js'
        }))
});
```

need a configFile